# Problems submitting form in hosting provider

Tags: php, web-hosting

I uploaded a form to my server. but no values are posted. which means the form isnt submitting . Ive run the same script in my local machine and it works perfectly.

ive been in web development for a year now and i've never seen a problem quite like this one.

The form is just a simple one (plain html too with php to check the posted variables) so it shouldve worked.

Comment: An example of you code would be useful.

Comment: give us some code ... and try var_dump($_POST) at processing page

Comment: http://ediningexpress.com/form/ here is the link where i uploaded my form. all benchmarks and form data are ehoe'd or dumped

Comment: P.S:- This submission works some time and doesnt at other times.

Comment: for me works fine ... what browser you use ... I think you have to set action for some browsers ... just put same page as action ant try again

Comment: it works fine in mine too right now but doesnt work sometimes.

Comment: sorry but this isnt a joke it the form really doesnt submit sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
<form name="frm" id="frm" action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
elements....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

for some browser have to set action, use something like this:

```
<form action='process_form.php' method='post'>
elements....
</form>
```

Comment: Which browsers? I never set action, and as far as I know it works. At least in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer (7 or higher), Opera and Safari. At least as my code is written; if the code is written in some other way perhaps you have to set action.